# Getting shorted result from 2-d array

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2-d object array. I want to get the top 5 values with highest `$prob[$i]->value` from array.

```
$prob[$i] = new stdClass();
while ($row1 = @mysqli_fetch_array($selectTag))
{
    $prob[$i]->value = ($pos_Count + 1)/ ($totalPOS_count + $distinct_pos_Count);
    $prob[$i]->tag = $row1['tag'];
}

arsort($prob);
var_dump($prob);
```

This code gives only 1 result.

How can I get the top 5 values in desc of of `$prob[$i]->value`?

Comment: do this in loop `$i++`

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
while ($row1 = @mysqli_fetch_array($selectTag)) {
    $prob[] = (object) array(
        "value" => ($pos_Count + 1)/ ($totalPOS_count + $distinct_pos_Count),
        "tag"   => $row1['tag'],
    );
}

uasort($prob, function($a, $b) { return strcmp($a->value, $b->value) } );

var_dump(array_slice($prob, 0, 5));
```

I added few things to your code:

- properly push to your array. For this you don't need `$i` at all if you manage to add all members in one command. I did it using simple trick with creating temporary array and converting it to object on the fly.
- define your sorting function using `uasort`.
- only take first 5 elements from sorted array using `array_slice`.

Comment: Add `return` to `compare` function